# Can I directly call an object from a PHP function in a single line?

Tags: php, object

I have a function `user_data`. It returns an object. I can access a property of that object directly by using

```
print user_data()->name ;
```

I am using PHP version 5.5.x. I recall years ago I could not directly access that way, I should have written

```
$user_data = user_data();
print $user_data->name;
```

How can I be sure that the syntax is right under any environment (it works in local but cannot be sure it will run on server).

Comment: PHP 5.3/5.4 are EOL'ed, you should be able to assume 5.5 and up, if not: change host or upgrade

Comment: Yes, that seems quite a good advice. Thanks.